# Kendo UI Grid not displaying any data in IE8 & IE9 only

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid that works absolutely fine in IE10/11/Chrome/Firefox.  However, in IE8/9 it completely fails to render any of the returned data.  It is hooked up to an OData Web Api 2 endpoint.  Here is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: "http://cross_site_url:port/api/TrackedContainers/get"
            },
            pageSize: 15,
            sort: { field: "EventTime", dir: "desc" }
                },
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "QrCode", title: "QR Code", width: 100 },
            { field: "Type", title: "Type", width: 150 },
            { field: "Location", title: "Location", width: 200 },
            { field: "Status", title: "Status", width: 90 },
            { field: "FailedCollectionReason", title: "Failed Collection Reason", width: 150 },
            {
                field: "EventTime",
                title: "Event Time",
                type: "date",
                format: "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",
                parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zz"],
                width: 150
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

For once, IE11's compatibility mode appears to be accurately mimicking the real world and also fails to display any results when set to IE8 Document mode. The URL above is obviously not the real one - it does however make a cross site call and as such I have tried enabling XSS in IE8 but to no avail.  Adding to trusted sites also does not make any difference.

Looking at the network traffic it, would appear that the grid doesn't even attempt the HTTP GET at all in  IE8/9.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add a CORS transport to jQuery? IE8 and 9 require the use of the XDomainRequest object to perform CORS requests which is not included in jquery.

Comment: Above your document.ready, add $.support.cors = true;

Comment: This was the problem.  Fixed by adding the above.  Ta muchly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did you add a CORS transport to jQuery? IE8 and 9 require the use of
>   the XDomainRequest object to perform CORS requests which is not
>   included in jquery. – Kevin B 41 mins ago
>
> Above your document.ready, add $.support.cors = true; – Robin Giltner
>   53 secs ago

The above fixed it, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dataType:json in your datasource

```
 transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/api/request/GetUrcs",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    batch: false,
```